# Is the top panel in Unity currently transparent by default?

Tags: unity, 11.04

Is the top panel of Unity transparent or solid by default at the moment?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solid, but you can make it transparent using the CompizConifg Settings Manager `ccsm`:

[image]

Comment: How can I turn the opacity on only for the top menu panel and not for every window. All window title bars are affected by this setting.

Comment: That's not the expected behavior (and not what I currently see), file a bug report.