# How do I make the top panel transparent in Unity?

Tags: unity, transparency

I'm using a fresh install of Ubuntu 11.10 using Unity.

I'm a newbie to Ubuntu and whilst researching various how-to's, I have seen screenshots where Ubuntu has the bar at the top of the screen shown transparent. I really like this, but I can't get it to do it on my box.

I have tried CCSM (2 different methods), Ambience theme editing (a copy) but it always shows as black.

I log out after each change and then log back in. Should I be restarting?

I'm running:

- Asus P5Q Pro
- Intel Core 2 Quad Q6600 @ 2.40GHz x4
- GeForce 9600GT
- 32-bit OS
- 4x 1GB DDR2 RAM Modules (although BIOS only shows I'm using ~3GB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you have said you have been changing settings in CCSM but they don't appear to have taken effect (and you have actually run the accepted [answer in this AU question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29983/is-the-top-panel-in-unity-currently-transparent-by-default)), my immediate thoughts are to check that you are indeed running the Unity 3d interface.

Whilst logging into the *Ubuntu* session, you are not given an immediate "You are using fallback mode" or a similar message.

Note - when using *Gnome-Shell* but you are unable to actually run this interface you "fallback" to the *Gnome-Classic* interface.  You are warned that this is happening by a pop-up message.

For the Unity interface, there is a silent "fallback" to Unity 2D (i.e. no pop-up message).  See the linked question below as to how to determine if you are using Unity 3D or Unity 2D.

As to why you possibly are using Unity2D without knowing it - this is likely to be due to your graphics card and/or drivers - I've linked to a question below how you can determine if you have Unity 3D support.

---

Linked Question:

1. [Am I using Unity or Unity 2D?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62001/am-i-using-unity-or-unity-2d)
2. [How do I tell if Ubuntu supports hardware-accelerated graphics on my laptop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33873/how-do-i-tell-if-ubuntu-supports-hardware-accelerated-graphics-on-my-laptop/65268#65268)

Answer (score 0):

Install Confity A.K.A Configure Unity from Software Center 
Click on Panel and reduce Opacity to Zero. See the picture Below.[image: Screen Shot]

You can also get Confity from [HERE](http://sourceforge.net/projects/confity/files/latest/download)